# How to remove arrows pointing towards 0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

I've been struggling with removing these arrows as shown in the picture. It appears that I get more of these arrows the more graphs I have. And if I don't add any graphs they are completely gone. Hope someone can help me out there!

[image]

---

This is my code for this graph:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.7\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
        xtick=data,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1600,
        %grid=major, % Display a grid
        %grid style={dashed,gray!30}, % Set the style
        xlabel=Gewicht $m$, % Set the labels
        ylabel=Spannung $U$ Peak to Peak,
        x unit=\si{\g}, % Set the respective units
        y unit=mV,
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=x, mark size=5, red, smooth]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe1, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

        \addplot+[mark=x, mark size=5, blue, smooth]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe2, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

        \addplot+[mark=x, mark size=5, green, smooth]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe3, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

        \addplot+[mark=x,mark size=5, brown, smooth]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe4, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

        \addplot+[mark=x,mark size=5, purple, smooth]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe5, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

        \addplot+[black, dashed]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        table[x=Gewicht, y=b, col sep=semicolon, mark = none] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

         \node[label={y=0,0863x+312,65}] at (axis cs:7000,650) {};

        %\addplot[blue]
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
        %table[x=Membranabschnitt,y=160,col sep=semicolon, mark=none, dashed, y={create col/linear regression={y=160}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table {dreizeilentabelle.csv};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I couldn't copy in all of my code, cause it had too many characters, but I was able to isolate the specific graph. Code of whole document which will result in the graph:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places,
    round-precision     = 2,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.7\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
            xtick=data,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1600,
            %grid=major, % Display a grid
            %grid style={dashed,gray!30}, % Set the style
            xlabel=Gewicht $m$, % Set the labels
            ylabel=Spannung $U$ Peak to Peak,
            x unit=\si{\g}, % Set the respective units
            y unit=mV,
        ]
            \addplot+[mark=x, mark size=5, black]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe1, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

            \addplot+[mark=x, mark size=5, black]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe2, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

            \addplot+[mark=x, mark size=5, black]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe3, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

            \addplot+[mark=x,mark size=5, black]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe4, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

            \addplot+[mark=x,mark size=5, black]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            table[x=Gewicht, y=Reihe5, col sep=semicolon, only marks] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

            \addplot+[black, dashed]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            table[x=Gewicht, y=b, col sep=semicolon, mark = none] {PeaktoPeakA.csv};

             \node[label={y=0,0863x+312,65}] at (axis cs:7000,650) {};

            %\addplot[blue]
            % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in the .csv file (on top)
            %table[x=Membranabschnitt,y=160,col sep=semicolon, mark=none, dashed, y={create col/linear regression={y=160}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table {dreizeilentabelle.csv};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Needed PeaktoPeakA.csv file:

```
Nummer;Gewicht;Reihe1;Reihe2;Reihe3;Reihe4;Reihe5;ReiheA;b
1;4782;718;301;704;746;881;670;725
2;7172;830;1405;937;984;1034;1038;931.594
3;9742;933;1522;1204;931;919;1101.8;1153.38
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: From the presented code it is very unlikely that the arrows are coming from that.

Comment: I thought the same, but if I remove every \addplot entry there are no arrows. I'm using Overleaf, if that is making a difference.

Comment: Please post complete code that produces this result and also the csv file so that we can compile it for ourselves.

Comment: With the code you added, there is no arrow pointing towards 0 on the graph.

Comment: I used the exact same code I posted, I even copied out the code I posted and for me it still shows the arrows. Downloading the .pdf still shows it.

Comment: Delete all auxiliary files created during compilation and compile again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the error myself. The .csv files where originally made in excel, cause some of them had way more than 1000 rows. I saved it from Excel as a .csv and removed all , with . so Latex can understand it. I don't know how or why, but by using this method, it will show the arrows. If I just copy the content of the .csv file, create a new file with the same name and paste in the same .csv content and then upload it, the arrows are gone.